# Get FeatureId of target in popup on vector layer in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

The below code works ok, I get lots of interesting data in getFeatureId.
How do I get my hands on that in the popup ?

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([53.505, -7.09], 7);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.etc.etc/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'osm..'
}).addTo(map);

var VectorTileOptions = {
  rendererFactory: L.canvas.tile,
  attribution: '',
  interactive: true,
  getFeatureId:function(feat){
    return feat.properties.routes
  }
};

var TilesPbfLayer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(tileurl, VectorTileOptions).addTo(map);

var popup = L.popup();
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
  popup.setContent("how do i get the feature Id ? ")
});
TilesPbfLayer.bindPopup(popup)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can get a click event on the tile layer, and its got a layer with my stuff in

```
TilesPbfLayer.on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.layer)
        popup.setContent(e.layer.properties.routes)
})
```